# Class Instance Creation - difference

Tags: class, instance, difference

if i have 2 really small class and one inherits from the other, can someone tell me whats the difference is when creating an instance of it? Example:

```
public class Animal {
    public void shout() {
        System.out.println("Animal");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void shout() {
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
}
```

If i now want to create an instance of Dog, i usually do it like this:

```
Dog barkie = new Dog();
```

But i could also do:

```
Animal barkie = new Dog();
```

It seems to me  that both do the same, but is there any actual technical difference? I hope you understand what my problem is.. creating an instance by the class itself or with the super class of it, i dont see the difference.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, according to me also there is no technical difference  in your classes. If you add a property / function to Animal class that will be available to Dog class also because of inheritance of Animal class, but reverse is not true. Keeping this in mind you can create a class that is inheritable or create a new class extending other class where you can add more functions without changing inherited class.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!

Comment: Welcome and cheers.